# Modified file content after upload

Tags: python, upload, python-requests, digest-authentication

The posted **Python code** is used to upload a file to an internal server which is configured for WebDAV. Of course URL and credentials are faked here. The problem is that the uploaded file content looks like shown (see below). I'm interested to upload just the three real content lines in the middle.
**What did I wrong?**
(*When using curl with --user and --digest it does work*)

### Uploaded File Content

```
--6cb2e8363c8d7f9191d2068b62828985
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="demo.properties"
Content-Type: text/plain

title=demo
context=upload
message=hello world 3!

--6cb2e8363c8d7f9191d2068b62828985--
```

### Python Code

```
from requests import put
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

url = 'http://internal-demo-url/uploads'
with open('demo.properties', 'rb') as handle:
    headers = {}
    files = {'file':('demo.properties', handle, 'text/plain')}
    response = put(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('xxxxxx', 'yyyyyy'),
                        files=files, headers=headers)
    print(response.status_code)
```

### The curl command

The url and the credentials are faked of course but that's the curl command that did work fine (line break ^ in Windows):

```
curl -XPUT --digest -T demo.properties ^
     --user "xxxxxx:yyyyyy" ^
     http://internal-base-url/uploads/demo.properties
```

Comment: Show us the `curl` command that works.

Comment: @Tarique I added the requested command in section "The curl command"

Comment: i hope the url being used is same in both the scenarios and do not specify headers in requests if you are not setting any header. Also please tell us what exact error are you gettting. what is `response.status_code` ?